Isolate null value with REGEXP_LIKE
I need to isolate a string result
which contains a null value.
The idea is to recognize when a string sentence contains a value that is null.
WITH test_data (text_value) AS (
  SELECT 
    'null,test' 
  FROM 
    DUAL 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 
    '12345678' 
  FROM 
    DUAL
) 
SELECT 
  td.text_value, 
  CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(NULL, '.') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS VALID 
   FROM 
     test_data td

The expected result is to isolate a result that has a null value
null,test  N

Why not simply use good old LIKE without this regex stuff?

The string 'null', either on its own as 'null' or as part of a longer string like 'null,test', is not the same as null. Which are you actually looking for? If you really want to identify null values, use is [not] null. Also your regexp_like is testing null, not the value in text_value, so that will never be true.

You could eschew invoking regular expressions entirely here, and just use a LIKE trick:
SELECT
    td.text_value,
    CASE WHEN ',' || td.text_value || ',' LIKE '%,null,%' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS VALID
FROM test_data td;

By the way, it is generally bad practice to store unnormalized CSV data in your SQL tables.  It would be better to instead store each component of every CSV string in a separate row, and logically connect them all via some other type of ID column.  Then, you could use a regular WHERE clause to check for the presence of a null string value.
